# Location of zeroes of the sum of a linear function and an exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive real constants. Consider the function $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ defined as
$$ f(z)=1+z+ae^{-bz}.$$

My question is:

> Can we find a "useful" sufficient condition on $a$ and $b$ that guarantees that $f$ has no zeroes on the closed positive half-plane $R=\{z \in \mathbb C : {\rm Re}(z) \geq 0\}$?

Some initial observations:

- $a < 1$ is a sufficient condition that ensures that $f$ has no zeroes on $R$. Indeed if $a < 1$, then $|ae^{-bz}| \leq a < 1 \leq |1+z|$ for all $z\in R$.
- $b = 0$ is a sufficient condition that ensures that $f$ has no zeroes on $R$. Indeed, if $b=0$, then $f(z)= 1+z$, whose only zero lies at $z = -1$.

But ideally, I would prefer to have a statement that says, "If $a$ and $b$ **together** obey such-and-such inequality, then $f$ is guaranteed to have no zeroes on $R$". This inequality should have $a < 1$ and $b = 0$ as special cases. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

[This question arose when studying a Laplace transform representation of solutions to a class of integral equations. Any progress on this question will improve my understanding of how the asymptotic behaviour of my solutions depends on parameters.]

---

**Update:** I've made some progress with this, but my argument isn't really a complex analysis argument, and I feel like there is an even stronger sufficient condition out there...

So here is what I've done. We already know what happens when $a < 1$, so we'll focus on the $a \geq 1$ case. I claim that if 
$$ b < \frac{\cos^{-1}(-\tfrac 1 a)}{\sqrt{a^2 - 1}},$$
then $f$ has no zeros on the positive half-plane $R$.

Indeed, suppose $z=x+iy$ is a zero of $f$, with $x \geq 0$. Then we have
$$ \begin{align} 1+x+ae^{-bx}\cos by = 0 \\ y - ae^{-bx}\sin by = 0\end{align}$$
To satisfy the first equation, we must have
$$ \cos b y \leq -\tfrac 1 a,$$
which implies that
$$ |y| \geq \frac{\cos^{-1}(-\tfrac 1 a)}{b}$$
and also that
$$ |ae^{-bx} \sin by| \leq \sqrt{a^2 - 1}$$
Hence the second equation is inconsistent with the inequality $b < \frac{\cos^{-1}(-\tfrac 1 a)}{\sqrt{a^2 - 1}}$, which proves the claim.

Comment: Perhaps this works: map left half plane to the unit circle with $\dfrac{z+1}{z-1}$, so all zeros of $f(\dfrac{z+1}{z-1})$ will lie in unit circle. using Rouche's theorem or other property of the unit circle, find a relation between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @user108128 Thanks for your response, but I've just managed to figure this thing out anyway. It turns out that my sufficient condition is also a necessary condition. There is a simple argument, using the intermediate value theorem, that proves that you can find a zero if my condition holds.